# Spring Boot App memory consumption

Tags: java, spring-boot, memory-management, heap-memory

1) Ours is a Spring Boot/Java 8 application that we run using 
   xms = 256 MB, xmx = 2 GB

2) Our release engineers are running **TOP** command on the unix server where the 
   application is running and are reporting that application is using **3.5 GB**

3) When I profile our application's production JVM instance using **VisualVM**, 
   I see the used heap size shows only about **1.4 GB**

Any thoughts on why the memory consumption numbers are so different between #2 and #3, above?

Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: xmx 2 GB means your application gets a maximum of 2 GB virtual memory in `jvm`. So, in host PC it may be a some more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-Xmx` parameter only sets a maximum size for the Java **heap**. Any memory outside the Java heap is not limited/controlled by `-Xmx`.

Examples of non heap memory usage include thread stacks, direct memory and perm gen.

The total virtual memory used (as reported by `top`) is the sum of heap usage (which you have capped by using `-Xmx`) and non heap usage (which cannot be capped by `-Xmx`).

So, the numbers in #2 and #3 are not comparable because they are not measurements of the same thing.

They will never be the same but if you want to bring them closer to each other (or at least have more control over the amount of virtual memory used) then you might consider using ...

- `-XX:MaxPermSize` to limit perm gen size
- `-XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio` to facilitate more aggressive heap shrinkage